# Django: how to use the keyword static in admin.py

Tags: django

In Django template, I could use the configured static path as:

```
{% load static %}
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'css/main.css' %}">
```

how to use the same static keyword correctly in *admin.py*, as show below inside the *img* *src*?

```
class CustomerAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ['customer_id', 'download_pdf', 'first_name', 'last_name']

    def download_pdf(self, obj):
        return format_html(f"<a href='{obj.pk}/pdf' target='_blank'>"
                           f"<img alt='PDF' src='{static}svg/document.svg'>"  # this {static} has error
                           f"</a>")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
def download_pdf(self, obj):
        return format_html(f"<a href='{obj.pk}/pdf' target='_blank'>"
                           f"<img alt='PDF' src='static/svg/document.svg'>"
                           f"</a>")
```

As if you try `static/` css name or file name it will work in in your HTML template too. You can try this in your admin.py

Comment: I know this will work but I don't want to hard code it like this, thanks